# HIDPI support with ASUS Zenbook and 4k Monitor

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have been having some significant issues getting Ubuntu to work nicely on a brand new ASUS Zenbook UX510U and an accompanying 4k LG 27UD58 monitor.

- When attaching the monitor via a HDMI cable and configuring the resolution to the recommended 3840 x 2160 the screen is flickering considerably. The laptop's screen is totally fine. Running `xrandr` I have found that the refresh rate detected by Ubuntu is only 30 Hz but the monitor should run with 60 Hz.

  I have tried a number of things to try and manually set the refresh rate on the monitor to no avail, including using `cvt 3840 2160 60` to grab the details I need and then using `xrandr` to create a new mode and assigning it to the monitor. This tends to screw up the display altogether and it ends up turning off the monitor, stretching the display as if to fit over both screens and pushes the mouse out of sync. It also displays an error message that I can't read as it is pushed partially off screen.
- The second issue I am having is related to Ubuntu's rendering of application user interfaces. I had installed PHPStorm and other Java based applications and noticed that their was some really small text along side some regular sized text. I additionally noticed that in PHPStorm an other applications which may not be Java based that other components such as radio buttons, checkboxes and normal buttons are much smaller and seem to have no padding/spacing around them. See this screenshot of Compiz Settings to illustrate:

  [image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

  The first screenshot at the top displays CompizConfig Settings Manager on my current machine running Ubuntu and the bottom one shows how it looks on my Zenbook.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix these issues or am I out of luck? I read that HIDPI isn't necessarily supported fully at the moment but the developers are looking to start working on it soon.

**Computer/Graphics:** ASUS Zenbook UX510U, Nvidia Geforce GTX 960M

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Also seen the same issues on Ubuntu 17)

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with the LG 24UD58 4K monitor.  To correct the unsteady display I found that I needed to upgrade from the 4.4 to the 4.10 kernel using the hardware enablement stack as found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).  After upgrading Ubuntu started using the amdgpu instead of an LLVMpipe driver.  Ubuntu now looks great on the LG monitor. xrandr shows it running at 4K @ 60 Hz.

Scaling is still a mixed bag.  Ubuntu is fine (except the login screen). Some third party software is in tiny print.  I have noticed that in my virtualbox VM's Windows 10 scales nicely, but Ubuntu Mate (17.10 beta) and anything using gnome 3 has uneven scaling as in originator's example.